# Obter valor 3 linhas após determinada palavra

Tags: regex

Tenho o OCR abaixo e estou precisando obter o valor 254.878,00, no regex que fiz está pegando o valor 8.571.962,06. Pela palavra `OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES` seria o ideal em função do texto ser negrito e sempre tem uma qualidade boa após a extração do OCR.

```
9135,456,07  
8.571.962,06  
OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES  
Rendimentos isentos e não tributáveis  
0.00  
254.878,00  
0,00  
Rendimentos sujeitos a tributação exclusiva/definitiva  
Rendimentos tributáveis - imposto con exigibilidade suspensa
```

REGEX:

```
(?<valor>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})(?=\s*(?:\r\n?|\n)OUTRAS INFORMA.*?.*?ES\s*(?:\r\n?|\n))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua regex você colocou o trecho referente à "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES" depois do número, mas como o número que você quer está depois, então você deve inverter e colocar "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES" antes:

```
OUTRAS INFORMA..ES.*(?:\r\n?|\n)(?:.+(?:\r\n?|\n)){2}(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3}),\d{2})
```

Depois de "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES", eu coloco `.*(?:\r\n?|\n)` (zero ou mais caracteres e a quebra de linha).

Depois temos `(?:.+(?:\r\n?|\n)){2}`:

- `.+` é "um ou mais caracteres". Mas como o ponto por padrão não [corresponde a quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), eu garanto que ele só vai até o fim da linha (mas se quiser ser mais explícito, também pode trocar por `[^\n\r]+` - qualquer coisa que não seja `\n` nem `\r`).
- depois eu pego a quebra de linha: um `\r` seguido ou não de um `\n`, ou um `\n` sozinho (contemplando assim as quebras de linha do Windows, MacOs e Unix)
- tudo isso se repete duas vezes, garantindo que vou pular duas linhas depois de "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES" (o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{2}` indica que o trecho "vários caracteres + quebra de linha" se repete várias vezes, então nesse caso ele indica a quantidade de linhas a serem puladas)

Depois, eu pego o número. Como ele está entre parênteses, isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e por isso estará no primeiro grupo de captura (os demais parênteses começam com `(?:` e com isso eles [não formam grupos de captura](http://rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap)).

---

Algumas *engines* suportam o atalho `\R`, que corresponde a uma quebra de linha (seja o `\n` ou `\r` sozinhos, ou a sequência `\r\n`, entre outros - a lista completa varia conforme a linguagem). Então a regex também poderia ser:

```
OUTRAS INFORMA..ES.*\R(?:.+\R){2}(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3}),\d{2})
```

Comment: Excelente, deu certo aqui. Muito obrigado

Comment: Se fosse para eu pegar o valor 0,00 como eu faria para pular mais uma linha? @hkotsubo

Comment: @user2254936 No trecho `(?:.+(?:\r\n?|\n)){2}`, o número 2 indica que vai pular duas linhas. Então basta trocar pela quantidade de linhas que vc quer pular

Comment: deu certo não :( estou testado no https://regex101.com/

Comment: @user2254936 Ah, é porque a regex que pega o número exige que a parte `\.\d{3}` exista. Basta deixá-la opcional, assim: `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})` - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/4F0wED/1/)

Comment: Agora sim, muito obrigado